# LoginUtils gwt-syncproxy

Tags: android, gwt, authentication, gwt-syncproxy

I've been trying to connect my Android app to the AppEnging, following this page https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/.

According to that page, I should :

```
CookieManager userSession = LoginUtils.loginAppEngine("https://example.appspot.com",
"http://example.appspot.com/helloApp/greet",
"emailaddress@gmail.com", "password");
```

When I call LoginUtils.loginAppEngine it suggest me a different method, loginAppEngine(Activiyy parent,CookieManagerAvailableListener listener,Account account).

that I can't find in the project sources.

Any possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

First the project sources are available at the Google Code site. Just click on the source tab at the top and then click Browse below that. Specifically, you can look at the Sample activity and Application provided for an example (https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/source/browse/trunk/SPAAppTest/src/com/gdevelop/gwt/syncrpc/spaapptest/MainActivity.java#146).

Second, I'm not sure what you mean by "It suggest me a different method...". For use in Android, the second method you specified is the one that must be used in order to get the Android Context. Please review the [Android wiki](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-syncproxy/wiki/Android) for SyncProxy and see if you can clarify your issue.

**Update**: I just reviewed what you were saying, and I believe understand your issue. The method you called is actually for use in the Java standalone library. In Android, you provide an Account (retrievable from Android's Account Manager system). This way you don't directly handle the user's credentials, it is handled by the Account system. The MainActivity class shows you an example of utilizing the library code to automatically get the user to select their requested Account.